# Edit path for rails not get correct url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have big problem with my rails app. I create advanced blog for my schoolwork

i need to edit my comment, but my url return this '/posts/4%2F12/comments/4/edit' and not /posts/4/comments/12/edit

if I type the URL myself correctly I have access to the modification form that works

you can see my code here

show.html.haml

```
.article
  .container
    .row
      .col-lg-12
        .cover-image{:style => "background-image: url('#{@post.photo_url}');"}
        %h1.mt-4= @post.title

        #{I18n.l(@post.created_at)}
        %hr/

        %p.lead= @post.content.html_safe
        %hr/

        .card.my-4
          %h5.card-header Ajouter un commentaire :
          .card-body
            = render 'comments/form', comment: @post.comments.build

        .media.mb-4
          .media-body
            - @post.comments.each do |comment|
              %h5.mt-0= comment.content
              %h5.mt-0= comment.user_name
              %h2 Edit user
              = link_to edit_post_comment_path([@post, comment]) do
                %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "button"} Primary
              = link_to "Delete Comment", [@post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

comments_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:create]

def create
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user_name = current_user.nickname
  if @comment.save!
    redirect_to @post
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "error"
  end
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end


def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
 end


private

def comment_params
  params[:comment].permit(:content, :post_id)
end

def post_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users, only: :show

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'home#index'

  root :to => redirect("/users/sign_in")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass two arguments into `edit_post_comment_path` method instead of passing an array, like this:

```
edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i get this error message
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :post_id=>"4"}, missing required keys: [:id]


for this line 

                = link_to edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) do
                  %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "button"} Primary

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
link_to edit_post_comment_path([@post, comment]) do
```

try

```
link_to edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) do
```

or alternatively

```
link_to [:edit, @post, comment] do
```

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

Comment: i get this message for link_to [:edit, @post, comment] do

undefined method `edit_post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f1a418b9c70>:0x00007f1a448793c0>

Did you mean?  edit_post_comment_path
               edit_post_comment_url

Answer (score 0):

> use before_action in `Comments Controller`  for comments also

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
.....
.....

private

def set_comment
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
end
```

and then in views/comments/show.html.haml

```
edit_post_comment_path(@post, @comment)
```

give it a try...